# Android Navigation Drawer not styling

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio and created a navigation drawer using the template provided.  I can't seem to figure out how to change control the styles at all.  I want it to look something like this:

[image: Navigation Drawer]

Here's my styles file (**styles.xml**):

```
<resources>
    <!-- Main theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Brand colors -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Navigation Drawer -->
    <style name="ActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And here's my main activity with the AppCompat drawer inside (**activity_main.xml**):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.intravene.MainActivity">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.intravene.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Sorry, I'm a bit new to Android development.  What am I missing here?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to change. the nav drawer is suppose to slide over the content and not slide the content like you show

Comment: I'm more interested in changing the look and feel of it rather than the slide over.  Things like background color, text item color, text capitalization, etc.

Comment: you change all that in your fragment and adapter views

Comment: Okay, I apologize for my ignorance here.  Are you referring to the `fragment_navigation_drawer` file then?  That's the layout referenced in the fragment I posted about.

Comment: yes you change the background in the layout file and all the text stuff in your list adapter layout file